# Using OpenDNS for the 3g connection

Tags: dns

I'd like to use OpenDNS for the 3G connection on my Android phone. I have a phone with Android Lollipop. The phone is not rooted. I tried several apps for non-rooted phones ([DNS Changer (no root 3G/WiFi)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burakgon.dnschanger&hl=en),
[Fast DNS Changer(no root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mustafademir.fastdnschanger&hl=en),
[DNSet pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dnsetpro&hl=en),
[DNS Changer (without Root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thanh.dnschanger&hl=en), etc...). They are all based on the creation of a VPN connection. I tried them all and they work but if i turn off the phone and boot it, I need to restart the app manually every time. Is there a way to do it automatically ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a data connection's IP settings, unless you

1. are rooted, then you can use Linux-based approaches (e.g. `iptables`)
2. use an app that creates a VPN connection to a remote server that uses OpenDNS

Now, VPN on boot depends on the app you're using. I'm yet to encounter an app that creates a VPN tunnel on boot.

**Update:** For the record, a lot of apps these days create VPN tunnels on boot.